# Is there an R function that can sum several variables from several data frames?

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data that looks like this:

[image: click to see the picture of my data]

This data shows where in the world a bunch of companies have their offices. The names of companies start with a letter and four digits.

What I want to do is to create two variables that show (1) a total number of companies per country in a given year and (2) the total number of companies per country and year but only with respect to "Country of 1st ADDRESS".

Now, one problem is that the data is quite big and it was delivered in 15 separate .csv files. The data is for the following years: 2003, 2007, 2011, 2015, and 2019. Three csv files for each year. For example, for 2003 we have: data2003_part1.csv; data2003_part2 and data2003_part3.

To create the variables above, I think I can use something like this:

```
 library(tidyverse)
 data_2003_part1 %>% group_by(Country of 1st ADDRESS) %>%
      summarise(B0100=sum(B0100,na.rm = T))
```

What I don't know how to do is 1) indicate in the code above all companies and not only one as I do here and that 2) the code could run on all 15 csv files. I guess I need to merge them first and add the year variable? or is there any other way?

Comment: Please do not post an image of code/data/errors: it cannot be copied or searched (SEO), it breaks screen-readers, and it may not fit well on some mobile devices. Ref: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557 (and https://xkcd.com/2116/). Please just include the code, console output, or data (e.g., `data.frame(...)` or the output from `dput(head(x))`) directly.

Comment: Unless the files are huge I would start by creating a dataframe for each file, then merge them into one dataframe (using `rbind` or `merge` or whatever). It tends to save time in analysis to have everything in one dataframe.  There is more than one way to do this, though.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
#Code
myfun <- function(df)
{
  #Code
  new <- df %>%
    pivot_longer(starts_with('COUNTRY')) %>%
    group_by(name) %>%
    summarise_all(sum,na.rm=T)
  return(new)
}
#Load files
myfiles <- list.files(pattern = '.csv')
#List of files
L <- lapply(myfiles, read.csv)
#Apply function
L1 <- lapply(L,myfun)
```

Complex to help without data. Let me know about any issue.

Comment: thanks for this! I've got the error that sum is not meaningful for factors. For some reason, 0s and 1s for company names are factors. I'll try to make them numerical but need to find a relevant code without making country name variables into numeric. I'll get back to you soon.